# JUnit Could not find class

Tags: ubuntu, junit4, selenium-ide

I am new to JUnit and selenium server so any help is appreciated.

I am running ubuntu 12 with java 7 and selenium ide and server. I created a simple login test script with selenium IDE, and exported it to Java/Junit4/webdriver.

I then compiled that script using the following command

```
javac -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit4.jar -cp .:/home/sakamoto/SeleniumServer/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar LoginTest.java
```

This seemed to go through without any errors (or any messages to the terminal for that matter).

I am seeing this error when trying to run the unit test that was generated from selenium ide exporting to JUnit4 webdriver:

```
java -cp /home/sakamoto/SeleniumServer/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.example.tests.LoginTest
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: com.example.tests.LoginTest

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)

sakamoto@ubuntu:~/Workspace$
```

I also have the following lines at the end of my .bashrc file and was able to run the sample test with junit4.

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/share/java/junit4.jar
export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/share/java/junit.jar
```

So ... How do I get rid of the Could not find class: problem and run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that junit cannot find your LoginTest.class file on the classpath.

Assuming you have a directory structure like this:

```
/home/sakamoto/my-project/com/examples/tests/LoginTest.class
```

Then, try explicitly including the path to the `my-project` directory inside the classpath. For example, try this:

```
 java -cp /home/sakamoto/SeleniumServer/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar:/home/sakamoto/my-project org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.example.tests.LoginTest
```

I think that junit is uses classpath+package name to determine the location of LoginTest test. I'm guessing/hoping that junit will 1) find `/home/sakamoto/my-project` is in the classpath and it will 2) append the package directory `com/examples/tests` so that it looks for LoginTest.class inside `/home/sakamoto/my-project/com/examples/tests`.

It's been a while since I used selenium and, unfortunately, I don't have selenium set up or I'd test this! But hope that works.

Comment: Try using the full absolute path to directory that contains LoginTest.class: `java -cp /home/sakamoto/SeleniumServer/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar:/home/sakamoto/**change this to your path**/com/example/tests org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.example.tests.LoginTest`

Comment: That didn't seem to work either. Is there something else that's causing the system to not be able to find it? I can take out the package line in the java code, but I get the same results when I try to run it.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I might see what's going on. When you specify `com.example.tests.LoginTest` in the command line, then I assume junit is checking each classpath entry, and looking for `<cp entry>+/com/example/tests/LoginTest.class`. I'll update my answer for something else to try...